# wp_nav_menu custom Page class

Tags: menus, plugin-polylang

I am building a multilingual site with Polylang, and need to add custom class to my menus that groups together Pages about the same content.

For example, I have a Page "Happy" and it has a translated Page "Gelukkig" in Dutch. Polylang allows me to have different versions of the menu for each language, but I need that a common class is added to the link to the "Happy" / "Gelukkig" / ... menu element. (I will use that class to add an image before the text.)

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) I find

```
.menu-item-object-category
This class is added to menu items that correspond to a category.
.menu-item-object-tag
This class is added to menu items that correspond to a tag.
```

But categories and tags are only available for Posts as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a custom field to the page, let say we name it "custom_class". Then you echo it to HTML class.

```
class="menu-item <?=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_class', true );?>"
```